# How to define a keras custom loss function in simple mathematical operation

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I define a custom function `my_sigmoid` as following:

```
import math
def my_sigmoid(x):
    a =  1/  ( 1+math.exp( -(x-300)/30 ) )
    return a
```

And then define a custom loss function called `my_cross_entropy`:

```
import keras.backend as K

def my_cross_entropy(y_true, y_pred):
    diff = abs(y_true-y_pred)
    y_pred_transform = my_sigmoid(diff)
    return K.categorical_crossentropy(0, y_pred_transform)
```

My keras backend is using tensorflow.
And the error shows

> > TypeError: must be real number, not Tensor

I'm not familiar with tensorflow and don't know how to use custom loss.

The following are my model structure and error message:

```
import keras.backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D, Dropout, Flatten, Dense

model=Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(512,(5,X_train.shape[2]),input_shape=X_train.shape[1:4],activation="relu"))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(100,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(100,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(50,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(10,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(1,activation="relu"))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=my_cross_entropy)
model.fit(X_train,Y_train,batch_size = 10,epochs=200,validation_data=(X_test,Y_test))
```

[image]

And the shape of `X_train` and `Y_train` is :
`(120, 30, 80, 1)`
and
`(120,)`

Comment: Can you post a complete small example?

Comment: I don't know hot to post my data on SO...........

Comment: Not your data, post the code you use and the point where the error is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
diff = abs(y_true-y_pred)
```

into

```
diff = K.abs(y_true-y_pred)
```

same for

```
math.exp()
```

change that into

```
K.exp()
```

abs and Math.exp are functions that cannot handle Tensors. If you still have problems refer to : [Custom Loss function Keras Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45279085/custom-loss-function-keras-tensorflow)